How Airflow SQLExecuteQueryOperator print messages in log
I am using Airflow SQLExecuteQueryOperator to execute a pl/pgsql script on postgres database. In my pl/pgsql script, there are RAISE NOTICE command to print out information. These messages aren't printed out in Airflow log. Is there a way to make Airflow log printing messages from sql execution?
An example to reproduce:
dag.py
SQLExecuteQueryOperator(
   task_id = 't1',
   conn_id = 'conn1',
   sql = 't1.sql'
)

t1.sql
DO $$ 
BEGIN 
    RAISE NOTICE 'hello'; 
END $$;


The Airflow PostgresOperator uses the psycopg2 binary.
As a result this leaves you with having to read the notices attribute of the connection that is populated after a query is executed.
Add a handler option to your PostgresOperator and print the notice from the connection object after the query is executed.
import logging


from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator
import pendulum
import textwrap


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def log_notices(cur, **kwargs):
    for notice in cur.connection.notices:
        logger.info(notice)

@dag(
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule=None,
    start_date=pendulum.from_format("2024-09-23", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
    catchup=False
)
def example_dag():
    postgres_operator_1 = PostgresOperator(
        sql=textwrap.dedent("""\
            DO $$ 
            BEGIN 
            RAISE NOTICE 'hello'; 
            END $$;"""),
        handler=log_notices,
        postgres_conn_id="exampledb",
        task_id="postgres_operator_1",
    )

